# strange behaviour in awk sub replacement

Tags: bash, shell, awk, scripting

I've got a string a

```
[root@rh-1 ~]# echo $a
4 11 10 7 11
```

This set of values need to be checked against the id field in the file table

```
[root@rh-1 ~]# cat table
id  name            inuse  rules  
1   Critical data   0      ...    
2   Important data  0      ...    
3   Normal data     0      ...    
4   nc-test         0      ...    
5   schedule one    0      ...    
7   foo sc2         0      ...    
8   foo sc3         0      ...    
9   foo-sc4         0      ...    
10  foo_sc5         0      ...    
11  foosc6          0      ...
```

Wherever the id is one of the numbers in $a, I need to replace the value of the inuse column with 1.The rules column can be discarded

```
[root@rh-1 ~]# cat table | awk -v a="$a" ' {
  split(a,sid," ");   NF=NF-1;}
  { $NF=0;n=length(sid);
  for (i=1;i<n;i++)
    { if($1 == sid[i]){
      sub($NF,1);
      break;
      }
    }
    if($1=="id")
      print("mid  name    InUse" );
    else
      printf("%-25s\n",$0); 
    } '
```

The approach above works, but for some reason here, in the line
10  foo_sc5
instead of replacing the 0 at the end,
to
10 foo_sc5 1
it replaces as
11  foo_sc5 0

while all others are replaced correctly.

```
mid  name    InUse
1 Critical data 0        
2 Important data 0       
3 Normal data 0          
4 nc-test 1              
5 schedule one 0         
7 foo sc2 1              
8 foo sc3 0              
9 foo-sc4 0              
11 foo_sc5 0             
11 foosc6 1              
[root@rh-1 ~]#
```

Somehow the replacement only for that particular line is faulty. Can someone help ?

Comment: BTW, you should do the `split` once in the `BEGIN` block, not on every line. And it would be better to turn the elements of `a` into the keys of an associative array, rather than values of a regular array -- then you can use `if ($1 in sid)`

Comment: Do you want your output mangled (as compared to the input) like that? Because you can absolutely just change the field in place if you want.

Comment: @EtanReisner Changing in place as John suggested or something else ? I don't have any specification on the output alignment. Whatever looks best.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace `sub($NF,1)` with `$NF=1`.

`sub($NF,1)` uses `$NF` as a regular expression and, For the first occurrence in the line, it replaces with `1`.  Since `$NF` starts out as `0`, this means that the first zero in the line is replaced with a one.

By contrast, `$NF=1` merely sets the last column to one.

Comment: Works perfectly. And the explanation makes perfect sense. Thanks.